# Previously executed migration are not registered migrations

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm trying to update my database with those commands

`php bin/console make:migration`

this return success

But when I try

`php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

I have this error:

> > WARNING! You have 5 previously executed migrations in the database >>that are not registered migrations.

```
>> 2018-12-17 10:42:04 (20181217104204)
>> 2018-12-17 13:19:24 (20181217131924)
>> 2018-12-17 13:40:58 (20181217134058)
>> 2018-12-18 10:41:38 (20181218104138)
>> 2018-12-18 13:15:49 (20181218131549)
```

Thing is, the database listed here are not in my migrations table from my database and they are not in my Migrations folder either.

How can I remove those wrong migrations ?  Thanks.

Comment: Can't you just do [`$ php bin/console doctrine:migrations:version 20181217104204 --delete`](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-migrations/en/latest/reference/managing-migrations.html#managing-the-version-table) and so on for all five?

Comment: No because when I try to delete it:   Could not find migration version 20181217104204  

I don't know why I see migrations that are not existing in my folder or database :(

Comment: just to clarify: in your database are you checking in the migration_versions table ?

Answer (score 12):

This is a year old, but I've had problems a few times where I delete old migration files because they aren't relevant or whatever reason and had the same issue.  I think the correct way to handle this is to delete references from the table directly.

```
php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "delete from migration_versions where version = '2020181217104204'";
```

*EDIT* - newer versions of Symfony are now using a "doctrine_migration_versions" table.

```
php bin/console doctrine:query:sql "delete from doctrine_migration_versions where version = '2020181217104204'";

Etc..
```

Answer (score 4):

Encounterd the same probleme : I had previously copied already executed migration to the newly created migration table (due to doctrine update).

Renaming all version names as follow saved the day : 20190408092436 --> DoctrineMigrations\Version20190408092436

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for! After recently updating to Symfony 4, the migrations bundle now requires the new naming of entires in the migrations table. Cheers !